# Sitecore multi-language solution is it ok to mix translated and un-translated content

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore is it appropriate, or sensible, to mix translated and un-translated items together?

Say I have a products page which is translated into every language supported by the site, then beneath the products item I wish to have some products which apply to every language and some which only need to have one language version?

As an example, say the English site has products 'A', 'B' and 'C', but the German version also includes a special German-only product 'D', I would like a user browsing the English site to see only 'A', 'B' and 'C' and a user browsing the German version to see 'A', 'B', 'C' *and* 'D'.

I know that this is possible, but what I really want to know is what are the drawback of just mixing fully translated items with ones which exist in only one language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will indeed be possible to build a setup like you describe in your explanation. Drawbacks will in my opinion be the ability to manage all different languages for the content managers. When you see a products folder with products a,b,c,d,e,f and g it will be in your situation harder to tell what products are not shown on the website in German for example. Other then that I think you will have to be alot more careful in coding your website. We have an unwritten rule where we say that if a Sitecore website has more then 80% of the content structure shared we keep everything in one content tree. Offcourse deviding the websites (languages) over different nodes in Sitecore has disadvantages aswell. One advantage is however, that it's easier for content managers to work with. (1 content structure)

Hope this helps you a bit!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When you mention being more careful in coding, I presume you just mean checking for items having versions in particular languages?

Comment: when you draw items from sitecores api like `.Children` or `database.GetItems()` you only get items that have the language version your context is set to so theres no greater risk there. although i would also advice to test that stuff.

Comment: Yes that is indeed what i mean mdresser.